# bitwise operations robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a keyword which returns a integer and I need to write another keyword that will extract the info from it.
each bit in the byte indicates a motor is running, and multiple motors could be active at the same time

```
    motor:
    - 0: Station 1 active
    - 1: Station 2 active
    - 2: Station 3 active
    - 3: Station 4 active
    - 4: Station 5 active
    - 5: Station 6 active
    - 6: Station 7 active
    - 7: Station 8 active
```

Unable to find any documentation on bitwise operations in Robot Framework.

Thank you

Comment: Please read [mcve] and edit  your question. Have you tried any code? what are your trials and errors? what exception you got if tried any code? Do you think that headline is in sync with the explanation ? Does the data your provided gives any idea about the problem you explained? Please make it understandable

Comment: This may not be what you want to hear, but I dont need a code answer, I rather looking to figure out how its done.
Its my first time using anything other than C, my new job needs me to do some hardware testing too. I have pretty much figured most of it by going through a lot of documentation. 
But this is one thing, I haven't been able to figure out. I'm just stuck at the very beginning, of this one issue, so no code to say I have tried this and got this error and such. 
Ill still do my best to edit the question.

Comment: @ojoshicomet: what you're asking isn't what [so] is about. It _is_ about the technical questions that start with non-working code and minimal examples. Although I am convinced that you are indeed putting in the work, I'd recommend looking at the answer below and posting a new question when you're running into a specific technical issue.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Just saying, questions do not have to start with a code, I understand it makes life easier for everyone, but not all technical questions need code do they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robot Framework is too high level and also has very close relations with Python which has all these operators, so it does not implement any kind of operator of its own, not even the basic arithmetic ones. All you have are keywords and Python.

There are two approaches you could choose from.

1. Implement the logic you need in pure Python as a [library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries) for Robot Framework.
2. Create a [user keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-user-keywords) in Robot Framework utilizing the existing [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword to do the logic.

Either way you will have to do the bit manipulation in Python and then wire that into Robot Framework. Both topic should have plenty of documentation available beside the ones I have linked.